# Setting up definition query to run through ModelBuilder on ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.6, definition-query

I am trying to make a model that will symbolize data quickly, but wanted to see if a model could perform a definition query or multiple definition queries on a large data set.

If this is possible, how could one set that up?

Comment: I dont think there is a tool to set a definition query but there are tool to create view or query layer that may let you do the same thing if you use a database to store your data

Comment: ArcGIS tools honor selections (any tool will only execute on the selected features) so use a Select by Attribute in your model which will function just like a definition query would.

Comment: Inline with @J.R you can use the Make FeatureLayer tool and set a query that will filter data, so just like a definition query but sometimes it may be more efficient to pre-process your data and do a select and export to a temporary location as suggested by user GBG above.

Comment: What does your test model look like?

Answer (score -1):

For me the Make Feature Layer tool didn't work, though the Feature Class To Feature Class tool did, you can set a definition query in that

[image]

Comment: I don't think the Feature Class to Feature Class can be used to define definition queries on data, you are applying a SQL expression during a conversion process, a definition query typically filters what is visible without altering the source dataset. Your approach makes a copy of the data excluding those rows that do not fulfil the SQl expression, which is a very different thing to a definition query.

Comment: This is true, making a copy of the dataset functions like a definition query though for a given run of model builder